# List images(01.png) and descriptions(01.txt) from directory

Tags: php, image, directory-listing

How can I display images from directory and get a corresponding description with each image, give the description exists.

in Directory //

```
01.png
01.txt
02.png 
03.png 
03.txt 
etc.
```

to display as //

```
<img src="01.png"><br>This is the description from the text file named 01.txt
<img src="02.png"><br>
<img src="03.png"><br>This is the description from the text file named 03.txt
```

I've been searching and searching, but can't find anything, so if someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. Also this is a very useful thing to be able to do for people wanting to create very simple galleries or lists of images and names.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try checkout glob http://php.net/manual/fr/function.glob.php, might help you.

Comment: This returned a lot of results very quickly from the Google machine, just sayin :)

Answer (score 3):

This is what you're looking for, as the description must be dynamically captured from a corresponding `.txt` file:

```
$dir = './';
$files = glob( $dir . '*.png');
foreach( $files as $file) {
    $filename = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '.txt';
    $description = file_exists( $filename) ? file_get_contents( $filename) : '';
    echo '<img src="' . $file . '"><br>' . $description;
}
```

What it does is grabs an array of `*.png` files using [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) from a given directory (`$dir`). Then, for each image, it gets the filename of the image (so `01.png` would be `01`), and appends `.txt` to get the name of the description file. Then, it loads the description file into the `$description` variable using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) if the description file exists. It then outputs the desired HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have the .php file in the same directory as the pictures and text files are.

You could use function `glob()` to read in all image-files as array from the directory, cut off the file extension (so '01.png' becomes '01') and append the file extension with string concatentation.

A working code example may look like this:

```
<?php
    $path_to_directory = './';
    $pics = glob($path_to_directory . '*.png');
    foreach($pics as $pic)
    {
        $pic = basename($pic, '.png'); // remove file extension
        echo '<img src=\"{$pic}.png\"><br>'; 
        if(file_exists($pic . '.txt'))
        {
            echo file_get_contents("{$pic}.txt");
        }
    }

?>
```

So definitely have a look on these functions:

- http://www.php.net/glob
- http://www.php.net/basename
- http://www.php.net/file_get_contents

Happy coding.

Comment: This won't do what you think it does: `$pic = basename($pic);` Also, there's no guarantee that the `.txt` file exists.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing.

make an array with all information.

```
$pics = array('img' => '01.png', 'text' => 'This is the description');

foreach($pics as $pic) {
    echo '<img src="'.$pic['name'].'" alt="">' . $pic['text'];
}
```

So you have to put your information in an array or a database otherwise you cannot map the desciption to your image.

When you want to read dynamicly the folder its a bit difficult.

You can look at [readdir](http://php.net/manual/de/function.readdir.php) or [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.glob.php) then you can read all images get the name and load the textfile with [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php) but i think its not a really performant way.

Answer (score 0):

Code Modified from here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

```php
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "../images/team/harry/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

//print each file name
foreach($images as $image)
{
    print "<img src=\"$image\"><br>This is the description from the text file named $image";
}
```

**ok, so this won't print the contents of the text file, but I'm sure you can further modify the code above to figure that out**

YEP

Comment: This doesn't load the description dynamically from a `.txt` file.

Comment: Nope, I'm not a coder for hire, some effort may be required on OP's  behalf

Comment: I guess I get -1 for trying to be as helpful as anyone should be expected to be.... :(

Comment: Your answer could in fact be a bit more helpful (e.g. pointing to (all) the functions in the PHP manual that one could use to solve the problem). But I'm definitely on your side that your answer is really more valueable than -1 reputation. So: "Protest +1" from me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Updated version of ZnArKs code, as he missed that you wanted the content of the files

```
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "../images/team/harry/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.png");

//print each file name
foreach($images as $image)
{
    $textfile = substr($image, 0, -3) . "txt";

    echo "<img src='{$image}'><br/>";

    if(file_exists($textfile))
    {
       echo file_get_contents($textfile) . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the `.txt` file exists.

Comment: WOW, this did it!!!
perfect. I was trying to figure out one of the older answers, and this just saved me a day of figuring things out. and it makes perfect sense, thank you soooo much!!!