# php foreach display img and matching txt file from a directory

Tags: php, foreach, filenames

I'm very unfamiliar with PHP. Thank you for your patience.

I've got a directory with about 500 images and growing, broken down into pages with simple PHP that fetches about 20 images at a time.

Previously I used the code below (everything works fine). It fetches the first 20 images and displays them in a 600x300 pixel DIV, with a logo DIV that sits fixed in the corner:

```
    $dir = 'photography/bnt/images/';
    $files = glob($dir.'*.jpg');
    for ($i=0; $i<=20; $i++)
    {
    $all = $files[$i];
    echo '<div class="sixbythree-image"><img src="'.$all.'" /><div class="sixbythree-logo"></div></div>';
    }
```

I decided I'd like to add a description file for each image, and have it pop up next to the logo DIV. After some searching I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231610/list-images01-png-and-descriptions01-txt-from-directory) and tried to apply it as follows:

```
    $dir = 'photography/bnt/images/';
    $files = glob($dir.'*.jpg');
    foreach (array_slice($files,0,20) as $all) {
    $filename = pathinfo($all, PATHINFO_FILENAME).'.htm';
    $description = file_exists($filename) ? file_get_contents($filename) : '';
    echo '<div class="sixbythree-image"><img src="'.$all.'" /><div class="sixbythree-logo"></div><div class="sixbythree-description">'.$description.'</div></div>';
    }
```

The images show up fine, the page displays without errors, but none of the .htm files (which are named the same as the images). I've tried several variations with/without extensions. Nothing shows up! What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

I apologize if this has been covered, I am perhaps not familiar enough with different types of solutions to know what to look for.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just a note, using `glob` is terribly slow especially with a lot of files -- you should use a `DirectoryIterator` instead, see the first comment for simple usage here http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: I believe this condition returns false "file_exists($filename)" and due to this your $description is always blank....

Comment: @JREAM Thank you, I will try to apply this!

Comment: Thank you @JayBhatt, how should I proceed?

Comment: Try to get the method by which your fetching the path...try something like  file_exists('photography/bnt/images/'.$all.'.htm');

Comment: Thank you again, @JayBhatt. I've tried pointing to all sorts of directories for any sort of result, but nothing will display (except for errors when I muck it up). Doing my head in. You can see an example of what I'm going for at http://rbsite.byethost16.com/stackoverflow.htm, if it helps? The blank yellow fields are where I'm trying to output the text descriptions, within the 600x300 pixel DIV. It's the same code as listed above, plus a usort function for most recent uploads. Is there another method I should be trying for all this, maybe?

Comment: got 404 on the link...

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't up for about 15 minutes after I posted. Works now!